# Local variable is allowed the same name as global variable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am aware in certain circumstances you can have a global variable and a local variable which have the same name such as

```
int i = 0;

public Something(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}
```

However I am confused to why this works. My code looks a little like this

```
TableRowSorter dataSorter; //Global Variable

public void setUpTable() {
    //Some Code
    dataSorter = new TableRowSorter(table.getModel());
    table.setRowSorter(dataSorter);
    DefaultRowSorter dataSorter = (DefaultRowSorter) table.getRowSorter(); //Local Variable
    //Some More Code
}
```

Why is the `DefaultRowSorter` allowed to have the same variable name as `TableRowSorter` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### In your first example:

Your outer `i` is not a "global variable," it's an instance property (sometimes called an instance variable).

The code in your first example works because when you use an unqualified symbol, the one with the *narrowest scope* is chosen. (The one declared "closest" to the code using it.) So the unqualified `i` in your `Something` constructor is the `i` parameter, and you have to use `this` to access your instance field. Gory details in [JLS§6.5.6.1: *Simple Expression Names*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1).

When there's no identifier with a narrower scope, you can omit `this.` to access fields (and methods), but not when there's a conflicting identifier with narrower scope.

Example:

```
class Example {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    Example(int a) {
        // These work:
        this.a = a;
        this.b = 42;

        // This also works and does the same thing as `this.b = 42;`
        b = 42;

        // This fails to set the instance field `a`, because it assigns the value
        // of the `a` parameter to...the `a` parameter
        a = a; // Doesn't do what one probably wanted
    }
}
```

#### In your second example:

You can successfully leave `this.` off the assignment to the instance field at the top of the method because you haven't declared your local variable *yet*. In Java, a variable declaration doesn't take effect until it's reached (unlike, say, old-style JavaScript where `var` gets hoisted).

So **until** the `DefaultRowSorter dataSorter = ...` line, when you use `dataSorter` unqualified, it refers to the instance field. **After** that, it refers to the local variable:

```
public class Example {
    private int a;

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        new Example().go();;
    }

    Example() {
        this.a = 42;
    }

    void go() {
        System.out.println(a);      // 42, `a` is resolved to the instance field
        int a = 67;
        System.out.println(a);      // 67, `a` is resolved to the local because it
                                    // is "closer" to this code
        System.out.println(this.a); // 42, because we qualified it
    }
}
```

Obviously I'd strongly recommend against doing that on purpose, but I'm sure you were already planning not to. :-)

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for correcting me there but I am still confused at why the second example works

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. I will accept it when I can

Comment: @Dan: Sorry about missing the point on the second example at first. I've also added a simpler (one hopes) demonstration of it in action.